# I am not able to see the entire grid in object or edit mode in the view port?

Tags: 3d-view

I see a grey area in my view port but before I was able to see entire grid with axis? How to get back the original view port look?[image] I am attaching a snapshot of the problem. I have used ctrl + alt+ Q just to show the problem from different angles

Comment: Hello and welcome. can you share your blend file https://blend-exchange.com

Comment: It looks like a Clipping problem, what does it give if you open the N panel > View > View and tweak the Clip Start and End values?

Comment: Thanks guys for trying to help. I just restarted my blender and it worked. It was weird!!

Comment: Thanks guys for trying to help. I just restarted my blender and it worked. It was weird!!